# JavaFX concurrent task design pattern for contunually returning ArrayLists

Tags: java, javafx, concurrency, task

I'm learning how to use `Task`s in JavaFX. I am trying to figure out the design pattern for a `Task` to continually update an `ArrayList` which is used by the Application thread.

Below is the code I have so far. It works but I want to make sure that I'm following best practices. Is this an appropriate design pattern? If not, can you suggest a better way?

Ultimately I am aiming to update a `Canvas` with pixel data generated by a long running `Task` but want to get the design pattern right on a simple case first.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.util.List;

interface Updateable {
    public void update(List<Integer> data);
}

public class TaskExample extends Application implements Updateable {

    private ListView<Integer> list_view = new ListView<>();

    public void update(List<Integer> data) {
        list_view.getItems().clear();
        list_view.getItems().addAll(data);  
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        MyTask task = new MyTask(this);

        Thread thread = new Thread(task);
        thread.setDaemon(true);     
        thread.start();

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(list_view));
        primaryStage.show();    

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}

class MyTask extends Task<Void> {

    private ObservableList<Integer> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    private Updateable ui;

    public MyTask(Updateable ui) {
        this.ui = ui;
        addListener();      
    }

    @Override
    protected Void call() throws InterruptedException {
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            data.add(i);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void addListener() {
        data.addListener((ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Integer> c) -> {
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                ui.update(data);
            });
        });
    };

}
```

## Updated

Updated `MyTask` according to @James_D's comment

```
class MyTask extends Task<Void> {

    private ObservableList<Integer> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    private Updateable ui;

    public MyTask(Updateable ui) {
        this.ui = ui;
        addListener();      
    }

    @Override
    protected Void call() throws InterruptedException {
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            final int j = i;
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                data.add(j);
            });
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void addListener() {
        data.addListener((ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Integer> c) -> {
            ui.update(data);
        });
    };

}
```

Comment: Seems good to me. Just wondering why you update the whole list every time ? Wouldn't be better to only transfer to `Updateable` the new data being added ?

Comment: Are nessery to display the intermediate result?

Comment: @Spotted - I agree with you for this simple example. However, the ultimate goal is to update a canvas with an array of pixel data, which will be different for every call to `update`, hence why the whole list gets supplied to `update`.

Comment: @AndreyM - Yes that is the whole point of the question. I want the task to continually provide the UI with data, not just when it finishes.

Comment: The code you posted isn't correctly written with regard to multithreading. You are changing the contents of the list in one thread, with `data.add(i);` and implicitly iterating through it in another (with `addAll(data)`). This is prone to `ConcurrentModificationException`s, if you get unlucky enough for an item to be added during the iteration, and other subtle errors. To fix, wrap the call to `data.add(i)` in `Platform.runLater(...)` instead of the call to `ui.update(data)`. However, it sounds like the real app is fundamentally different to this - can you post a more representative example?

Comment: @James_D - Thanks for you comment. I've updated the question with the new implementation of `MyTask`. Is that what you had in mind? Regarding the real app, I haven't started it as I am trying to ground my understanding of concurrency first. The reason I mentioned it was to justify returning the entire `List`, not just the appended values.

Comment: I think your updated code works correctly. However, it doesn't actually do what you describe: "I am trying to figure out the design pattern for a Task to continually supply the Application thread with *a new ArrayList*." (my emphasis). Your example doesn't provide a new list; it creates a single one, just one for the entire application, and updates it. This is quite different to what you describe.

Comment: @James_D - You are quite right. The application is doing what I want it to do, I misworded the question - I will update it to reflect this.